# both radio code and number input for calculation and the error about the file you asked for does not exist

Tags: html, radio-button, user-input

I tried to learn Javascript. I wanted to have both radio code and number input for calculation. I checked my code on https://validator.w3.org/ and solved any problems, but when I run it, I see the error " the file you asked for does not exist".
Because I'm beginner, I feel happy if help me, and rewrite my code.
With regards,
Mahdipour

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fa">
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>


<form onsubmit="return calcBMI();">
  
  <p>توجه. مقدار رنگ محاسبه شده در این سیستم برای پایده سازی یک لایه رنگ است</p><br>
  
  
  <p>لطفا رنگ مورد نظر خود را انتخاب کنید</p>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" id="bmi-metric" name="bmi-measure" onchange="measureBMI()" checked/> اکریلیک
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" id="bmi-imperial" name="bmi-measure" onchange="measureBMI()"/> پلاستیک
  </label>
 <label>
    <input type="radio" id="bmi-oil" name="bmi-measure" onchange="measureBMI()" checked/> روغنی
  </label>
  <br><br><br>
 
 
 <p>لطفا طول، عرض و ارتفاع اتاق را وارد کنید</p>
  طـول اتــاق
  <input id="bmi-weight" type="number"  min="1" placeholder="سانتی متر" required/> 
  <span id="bmi-weight-unit"> *</span><br><br>
 
  عرض اتاق
  <input id="bmi-height" type="number" min="1" placeholder="سانتی متر" required />
   <span id="bmi-height-unit"> *</span><br><br>
  
   ارتفاع اتـاق
  <input id="bmi-room" type="number" min="1" placeholder="سانتی متر" required/>
     <span id="bmi-room-unit"> *</span><br><br><br>
 
 
 
 <p>لطفا تعداد درب و پنجره های موجود در اتاق را وارد کنید. در صورت عدم وجود درب یا پنجره عدد صفر را وارد کنید </p>
 تعداد درب
  <input id="bmi-door" type="number"  min="1" required/>
  <span id="bmi-door-unit"> *</span><br><br>
  
تعداد پنجره
  <input id="bmi-window" type="number"  min="1" required/>
  <span id="bmi-window-unit"> *</span><br><br><br>
 
 
  <input type="submit" value="محاسبه رنگ مورد نیاز"/>
  <div id="bmi-results"></div>
</form>



<script>
function measureBMI () {
  // true = اکریلیک , false = پلاستیک , else = روغنی
  let unit = document.getElementById("bmi-metric").checked,
      weight = document.getElementById("bmi-weight"),
      weightu = document.getElementById("bmi-weight-unit"),
      height = document.getElementById("bmi-height"),
      heightu = document.getElementById("bmi-height-unit");
      room = document.getElementById("bmi-room"),
      roomu = document.getElementById("bmi-room-unit"),
      door = document.getElementById("bmi-door"),
      dooru = document.getElementById("bmi-door-unit"),
      windoww = document.getElementById("bmi-window"),
      windowu = document.getElementById("bmi-window-unit"),
}
 
function calcBMI () {
  // (A) Get elements
  let bmi = null,
      unit = document.getElementById("bmi-metric").checked, // true = اکریلیک , false = پلاستیک , else = روغنی
      weight = parseInt(document.getElementById("bmi-weight").value),
      height = parseInt(document.getElementById("bmi-height").value),
      room= parseInt(document.getElementById("bmi-room").value),
      door= parseInt(document.getElementById("bmi-door").value),
      windoww= parseInt(document.getElementById("bmi-window").value),
      
      results = document.getElementById("bmi-results");
 
  // (B) Calculate BMI
  // Metric BMI = Mass (kg) / Height (m) square 
  if (unit) {
    bmi = (2*(weight * room + height * room)-(door*90*210+window*150*150))/13;
  }
  // Imperial BMI = 703 X Mass (lbs) / Height (in) square 
  else if {
    bmi = (2*(weight * room + height * room)-(door*90*210+window*150*150))/8;
  }
   else {
    bmi = (2*(weight * room + height * room)-(door*90*210+window*150*150))/7;
  }
  // Round off
  bmi = Math.round(bmi * 100) / 100; // Round off 2 decimal places
 
  // (C) Show Results
  if (bmi < 18.5) {
    results.innerHTML = bmi + " - Underweight";
  } else if (bmi < 25) {
    results.innerHTML = bmi + " - Normal weight";
  } else if (bmi < 30) {
    results.innerHTML = bmi + " - Pre-obesity";
  } else if (bmi < 35) {
    results.innerHTML = bmi + " - Obesity class I";
  } else if (bmi < 40) {
    results.innerHTML = bmi + " - Obesity class II";
  } else {
    results.innerHTML = bmi + " - Obesity class III";
  }
  return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: The error you've mentioned looks more like the browser wasn't even able to find your file. How exactly did you try to run your file?

Comment: I wrote my code in notepad and then saved in htm format. In another try, I run it in "try it yourself" in https://www.w3schools.com/ website. (I should mention that I want to write my code in Farsi)

Answer (score 0):

You have two syntax errors in your code.

1. At the last line of your `measureBMI()` function you have:

```js
windowu = document.getElementById("bmi-window-unit"),
```

There should be semicolon `;` instead of comma `,`.

Also there probably should be comma instead of semicolon in this line of same function. But I'm not exactly sure what is your aim with this function. Currently you are assigning elements to variables but you are doing nothing more with those variables. The `let` keyword make these variables visible only inside the scope of `measureBMI()` function.

```
heightu = document.getElementById("bmi-height-unit");
```

2. In your `calcBMI()` function you have:

```js
 if (unit) {
    bmi = (2*(weight * room + height * room)-(door*90*210+window*150*150))/13;
  }
  // Imperial BMI = 703 X Mass (lbs) / Height (in) square 
  else if {
    bmi = (2*(weight * room + height * room)-(door*90*210+window*150*150))/8;
  }
   else {
    bmi = (2*(weight * room + height * room)-(door*90*210+window*150*150))/7;
  }
```

You are missing the condition in your `else if (condition) {` part.

Because of these syntax errors this javascript cannot be run and when you try to submit your form the `calcBMI()` is not defined. Because of that the browser tries to submit the form in standard way.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. You know, I want to write a calculator which includes radio button (with three choices), and when user chooses one of them it calculates different things, for example calculateing bmi or area of different shapes. Do you have any advice to write a code with these rules? Can my code work by editing errors you have mentioned?

Comment: I changed everything that you have mentioned. Now I have new error "NaN - Obesity class III".